# Split the values from ('1,2,3') to ('1','2','3') or (1,2,3) in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table field named `category_ids (text)` which saves another table's ids as `"1,2,3"`.

Now i want to use this `category_ids` to a sql `IN()` query. the query will  be like `tab1.category_id IN (select category_ids from tab2)`. but i'm facing issue as `select category_ids from tab2` returns `'1,2,3'` so `IN()` query not working.

Is there any simple way to convert `'1,2,3'` to `('1','2','3')` or `(1,2,3)` in sql?

Comment: Poor design decision to store comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tab1.category_id,
                  (select category_ids from tab2));
```

This is just a sample query, your actual one may differ.  But the point is that if you want to search for `'1'` inside a CSV string `'1,2,3'`, then there is a way to do it.

As others have already mentioned, you should avoid storing CSV data in your tables.  When I see `FIND_IN_SET` being heavily used there is usually a smell.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
tab1.category_id IN (select REPLACE(category_ids, '''', '') from tab2)
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why this would be a solution for the described problem?

Answer (score 0):

If `table2` has more than one row, you can use `exists` with `find_in_set()`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where  exists (select 1
               from table2 t2
               where find_in_set(t1.category_id, t2.category_ids) > 0
              );
```

Note that this is a very poor data structure.  You should have a single row for each category id in `table2`.  If you did, then the query would be simpler and have better performance.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . This addresses `table2` having more than one row.